# How should HTTP Server respond to HEAD request for chunked encoding

Tags: http, http-headers, httpresponse, rfc2616

I have a question on how does a HTTP Server response look like when a HEAD is sent to a resource and server decided to perform chunked encoding?

If a Server always wishes to perform chunked encoding for a GET on a specific resource, as it does not know the exact content-length while generating response, how should server behave when a HEAD is sent on the same resource.

Comment: I have a similar question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008095/what-response-header-should-http-head-method-get-for-a-dynamically-generated-fil

Comment: @smwikipedia check this https://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#http1.1c2 for Chunked Transfer-Encoding

Comment: @AK1 Thanks but that only explains what chunked transfer is. Not related to this question.

Answer (score 8):

The Transfer-Encoding header field is an aspect of the payload. For HEAD responses, you don't have a payload, thus no Transfer-Encoding header field; even if it would be used upon GET.

Comment: I wanted to understand whether response to HEAD request contains a Transfer-Encoding header set to chunked and will have not carry chunk size in hex for each chunk (without actual chunked entity) and end with a 0 followed by double CRLF.

Comment: HEAD response headers SHOULD be identical to a GET response. Content-Length and Transfer-Encoding MAY be omitted but it's fine if they're there. Of course there MUST NOT be a body on a HEAD response.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [W3C's specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4):

> The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request.

This means that if a response to a GET request contains `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` then the response to a corresponding HEAD request *should* contain that header too.

You can verify this in the wild:

`curl -I http://www.google.com/ # -I sends HEAD request`

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 09 Jan 2015 17:56:05 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=0.02
Transfer-Encoding: chunked`

Comment: RFC 2616 is not a W3C specification. Also it is obsoleted by RFC 7230.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Section 4.3.2 of 7230 is a superset of the semantics in 2616 -- it elaborates that payload header fields may be omitted in a HEAD response.