# What response header should HTTP HEAD method get for a dynamically generated file?

Tags: http, chunked, http-chunked

The [http spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) says about the HEAD request:

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT
>   return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained
>   in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical
>   to the information sent in response to a GET request.

And [also](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4):

> The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the
>   entity-body, in decimal number of OCTETs, sent to the recipient or, in
>   the case of the HEAD method, the size of the entity-body that would
>   have been sent had the request been a GET.

So if the requested resource is dynamically generated,  for the `HEAD` request, will the resource **ALSO** be generated? Should there a `Content-Length` header or `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header?

(I feel this is about how to implement the HTTP protocol.)

### ADD 1

I don't see the spec mandates `whether to` send Content-Length header or `how to` send it for a dynamically generated resource. Such dynamic resource will be sent with chunked transfer encoding and there'll be no `Content-Length` header if accessed with a `GET` method. So, if HEAD response should mimic GET response, the Contnet-Length should not be sent either.

Answer (score 1):

a) That's not the HTTP spec. It is the W3C copy of the now obsolete RFC 2616, dated 1999.

b) For the current spec, see https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#HEAD

To answer your question: if you don't know the payload size without actually generating it, not sending Content-Length in the HEAD response is ok.